# mod_dart is dead - help me rebuild it

Tags: dart

I've been watching and playing with dart since I first heard about it.  The idea is great, but one aspect of the language is still unattainable.  Server side processing.  I'm not talking about setting up an isolate to respond to http requests, I'm interested in real horsepower.

Sam McCall created the mod_dart apache module several months ago - but seems to have abandoned it.  It doesn't compile with the current version of Dart, and he doesn't respond to reported issues.  I forked his code on github, made a few changes - but while I'm able to get it to compile - I'm still missing something, as it won't load into apache.

Here is Sam McCalls mod_dart URL:
https://github.com/sam-mccall/mod_dart

Here is mine:
https://github.com/stutteringp0et/mod_dart

I've been adding more information to the issue posted on Sams project, but with no response - I'm turning here to find someone willing to help me make this happen.

I have a feeling that when the right person looks at it - the solution will be simple.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the compile errors (I think; please check!). See the issue for more details: https://github.com/sam-mccall/mod_dart/issues/1